# store TOML data in groovy

Tags: groovy, toml

I'd like to create a TOML file in groovy.

```
import groovy.toml.*

Map<String, Object> tomlData = [
  person: [ 
      firstname: 'Stefan', 
      lastname: 'Draeger', 
      age: 42, 
      birthday: new GregorianCalendar(1980, Calendar.MAY, 11, 1, 10, 45).time, 
      hobby: ["Garten", "Programmieren"] 
    ]
]

def builder = new TomlBuilder()

builder tomlData

builder.writeTo(?)
```

But which writer do I have to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write content to a file, then you could use `File.withWriter{...}` that creates writer and closes it after closure execution.

```js
new File('/my/file.toml').withWriter("UTF-8"){ w-> builder.writeTo(w) }
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withWriter(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Perhaps add some comments to this code line,  if it is ok.